# Magento 2.1 - display attribute group name

Tags: attributes, group

How can I display the group names above the attributes. I found the solution for Magento 1 but not for Magento 2.

Group 1
att 1
att 2
att 3

Group 2
att 4
.
,
I am using Porto theme on magento 2.1.

Comment: you mean you need attribute set name?

Comment: No I need a name of the group of attributes. e.g. Dimensions: , features ,...

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for this:

Create a block file and add this code:

```
protected $_groupCollection; 

public function __construct(
 \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Group\CollectionFactory $_groupCollection

) {
    $this->_groupCollection = $_groupCollection;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
public function getAttributeGroupId($attributeSetId)
{
     $groupCollection = $this->_groupCollection->create();
     $groupCollection->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_id',$attributeSetId);
     $groupCollection->addFieldToFilter('attribute_group_name','Grid Attributes');


     return $groupCollection->getFirstItem(); 

}

public function getAttributeGroups($attributeSetId)
{
     $groupCollection = $this->_groupCollection->create();
     $groupCollection->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_id',$attributeSetId);

     $groupCollection->setOrder('sort_order','ASC');
     return $groupCollection; 

}
 public function getGroupAttributes($pro,$groupId, $productAttributes){
    $data=[];
    $no =__('No');
    foreach ($productAttributes as $attribute){

      if ($attribute->isInGroup($pro->getAttributeSetId(), $groupId) && $attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront() ){
          if($attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($pro) && $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($pro)!='' && $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($pro)!=$no){
            $data[]=$attribute;
          }
      }

    }

  return $data;
 }
```

And after this call that in your phtml file

```
$groupid=$block->getAttributeGroupId($_product->getAttributeSetId());
$attributesgroups=$block->getAttributeGroups($_product>getAttributeSetId());

$productAttributes=$product->getAttributes();

$i=0;

$countAttributes=$block->getCountAttributes($product,$attributesgroups,$productAttributes);

foreach ($attributesgroups as $attributesgroup):
    $attributes = $block->getGroupAttributes($product, $attributesgroup->getAttributeGroupId(), $productAttributes);
if ($attributes) {
    ?>
    <h3 class="col label" scope="row"><?php echo $attributesgroup->getAttributeGroupName() ?></h3>
    <div class="additional-attributes-wrapper table-wrapper block">
        <table class="data table additional-attributes" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
            <tbody>   
                <?php foreach ($attributes as $attribute): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="col label" scope="row"><?php echo $attribute->getFrontendLabel() ?></td>
                        <td class="col data feature" data-th="<?php echo $attribute->getFrontendLabel() ?>"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product) ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <?php
}
    endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, could you please lead me what type of file block should I create and in which folder? Which .phtm should be edited?  I am still new in this and I would appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: Crate one custom module. Create block and phtml files in this. After this call your custom module block where you have to display this attributes.

Comment: check this link to create custom module 
https://inchoo.net/magento-2/how-to-create-a-basic-module-in-magento-2/