# Get Group Attributes Details By Group ID

Tags: magento2

Hello How To Get Group Attributes Name By Group ID

```
<?php 
$group_id = 20; // This is Group id
```

//what ineed is Get Groub Name Via ID of group

Comment: Following code will help you in this. [Magento 2.1 - display attribute group name](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/240418/91911)

Answer (score 0):

following link might help you to get attribute set group detail.

[Magento 2.1 - display attribute group name](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/240398/magento-2-1-display-attribute-group-name)

Thank you
Hiren Patel